# Show a page of an ASP.NET app from windows desktop app and get a result

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, maui

Consider the [ASP.NET Core MVC Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/start-mvc?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio) from msdn: I would like to show a page of the MVC app (e.g. the create a movie page) from a windows desktop app. However, the web page does not need to be embedded in a frame in a Winforms/WPF dialog. If the page is displayed in the current browser that is sufficient.

When the user has finished and the movie is created, the calling windows app should receive the newly created movie as a result. What I have so far:

1. Recreate the input form in Winforms/WPF and use the underlying apicontroller which has access to a repository of the MVC app (I have added this to the original tutorial).
2. Open the web page with `Process.Start` and add a parameter which identifies the calling client. When the user has finished, the web page notifies the client via an external message broker like RabbitMQ. The notification includes an id of the created entity allowing the desktop app to get the entity by id from the apicontroller.
3. Wondering if there is a native option with something similar to .net events or `var res = Form.ShowDialog()` involving .net MAUI or else.

Reason for this: I want a full web app which can be used virtually everywhere. But there will be an addin in a host windows app which should use as much as possible from the web app but integrates into the host app. Example: Outlook vsto addin with a button to create a movie and include the movie description and more in the email body.

Comment: Is the pop up in the maui you want? You can check the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/pop-ups) about it.

Comment: The host is a windows app, e.g. Winforms. I want to show an ASP .NET view when the user hits a button or something. That can be a Blazor page (from MVC app) or a page in Maui (whatever works best). After the user has finished the form I need a result from that page to work with it in the (Winforms) host app

Comment: You can try to accepted the data from the ASP .NET view and display it in the maui's view.

Comment: Sorry, I dont get it. Start from the beginning. From the Winforms app what do I have to call to show the view in the browser or as a Maui dialog?

Comment: Are the Winforms app and the maui app two different apps? If so, you can use webservice to get the data you want to show in the maui such as string or image and then display.

Answer (score 0):

I used the second option:

1. My ApiController has an additional action that returns the personal url for the form which is shown with `Process.Start`.
2. The client waits for a message in his own RabbitMQ queue and blocks all input while he is doing this.
3. The web page posts a message in the queue when the form is transmitted.
4. The client receives the message with an item id and can get the newly created item by id from the ApiController and work with that.

Thus I do not have to duplicate the form in a WinForms dialog. The user can create new items either from the desktop app or directly via the web app.